# eigenvalues of $p(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This question is related to the following question:

[Do $A$ and $p(A)$ have the same eigenvectors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683730/do-a-and-pa-have-the-same-eigenvectors)

Suppose again that $p(x) = a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0$ is a polynomial, and that $\sigma(A)$ denotes the set of eigenvalues (spectrum) of matrix $A$.  It is easy to show that if $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$, then $p(\lambda)$ is necessarily an eigenvalue of $p(A)$.  But it is not very clear to me if $\{p(\lambda): \lambda \in \sigma(A) \}$ constitutes the entire spectrum of $p(A)$?  Or can $p(A)$ have eigenvalues not belonging to $\{p(\lambda): \lambda \in \sigma(A) \}$?  How do we prove or refute this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over an algebraically closed field it's the entire spectrum, and you can see that  by considering the Jordan normal form.

In general, it might not be. For example, $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ has no real eigenvalues but $A^2$ has eigenvalues.

Comment: Indeed JCF is a simple way to see it.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just a follow-up comment.  It turns out that another similar way to see this is Schur's triangularization, i.e.  Since every $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ is unitarily equivalent to a triangular matrix, say, $T$, apparently $\sigma(p(A))=\sigma(p(T))=\{p(\lambda): \lambda \in \sigma(A)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that we're considering matrices over a algebraically closed field (such as $\Bbb C$).

Suppose that $p(A)$ has eigenvalue $\mu$. Then we note that if we set $q(x)=p(x)-\mu$, then
$$
q(x)= a(x-\lambda_1)\cdots (x-\lambda_n)
$$
for some numbers $a$ and $\lambda_k$. The $\lambda_k$ are precisely the values of $x$ for which $p(x)=\mu$.

Now, since $\det(q(A))=0$, we can conclude that $A-\lambda_k I$ is singular for some $k$. For this $k$, $\lambda_k$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Cool.  BTW, did you mean $\det(q(A)) = 0$ rather?

Comment: @syeh_106 Yes, fixed it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

This is true if the characteristic polynomial of $A$ splits into linear factors, i.e., if the spectrum of $A$ contains the all eigenvalues that exist in an algebraic closure of the field (and so in particular if we are working over an algebraically closed field like the complex numbers). To see this it suffices to extend the result you cited to generalised eigenspaces:

> For every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of a linear operator$~\phi$ and for any polynomial$~P$, the generalised eigenspace of$~\phi$ for$~\lambda$ is contained in the generalised eigenspace of$~P[\phi]$ for its eigenvalue$~P[\lambda]$.

The proof is simple: that generalised eigenspace of$~\phi$ consists by definition of the vectors in the kernel of $\def\id{\,\mathrm{id}}(\phi-\lambda\id)^k$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$, while the mentioned generalised eigenspace of$~P[\phi]$ consists of the vectors in the kernel of $(P[\phi]-P[\lambda]\id)^k$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$. But since $\lambda$ is clearly a root of $P-P[\lambda]$, the latter polynomial is divisible by $X-\lambda$, say $P-P[\lambda]=(X-\lambda)Q$, and then $(P-P[\lambda])^k=(X-\lambda)^kQ^k$ is a multiple of $(X-\lambda)^k$, and any vector annihilated by $(X-\lambda)^k[\phi]=(\phi-\lambda\id)^k$ is also annihilated by $(P-P[\lambda])^k[\phi]=(P[\phi]-P[\lambda]\id)^k$, which is the desired inclusion.

Now the result of the question follows as before. By hypothesis, the (direct) sum of the generalised eigenspaces for all eigenvalues$~\lambda$ of$~A$ fills the whole space. But each one is contained in the generalised eigenspace for the corresponding eigenvalue$~P[\lambda]$ of$~P[A]$, so the sum of those eigenspaces for all occurring values$~P[\lambda]$ also fills the whole space, and those values constitute the entire spectrum of$~P[A]$.