# Generalized eigenvalue space of $P(\lambda)$ and $\lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a linear transformation on a finite dimensional vector space, we know that the  eigenvalue of $P(A)$ is exactly $P(\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of $A$, $P$ is a polynomial, my question is if the generalized eigenvalue space of $P(\lambda)$ and $\lambda$ are the same? If not, is it

Comment: What have you tried? When you say you know that the eigenvalues of $P(A)$ are $P(\lambda)$, does this mean that you know a proof of this fact? If so, you could try going through the proof more carefully while keeping track of the generalized eigenspaces.

Comment: It is not quite true that the eigenvalues of $P[A]$ are precisely the same as the values $P[\lambda]$ where $\lambda$ runs through the eigenvalues of$~\lambda$, at least not if you take "eigenvalue" to mean one in the field over which the vector space is defined (so that there are corresponding eigenvectors in your space), and that field is not assumed to be algebraically closed. For instance take a matrix without eigenvalues (e.g., a rotation in the real plane) and $P$ its characteristic polynomial.

Comment: This question is not a precise duplicate of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1689389/eigenvalues-of-pa/), but my answer there does answer this question. While I am not fond of copy-paste, I'll do that here I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that all eigenvalues of $P[A]$ correspond to an eigenvalue of $A$, one must first of all assume that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ splits into linear factors, i.e., the spectrum of $A$ contains the all eigenvalues that exist in an algebraic closure of the field. Then one has

> For every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of a linear operator$~A$ and for any polynomial$~P$, the generalised eigenspace of$~A$ for$~\lambda$ is contained in the generalised eigenspace of$~P[A]$ for its eigenvalue$~P[\lambda]$. The generalised eigenspace of $P[A]$ for some eigenvalue$~\mu$ is the direct sum of the generalised eigenspaces of$~A$ for those eigenvalues$~\lambda$ with $P[\lambda]=\mu$.

Note in particular that there is no equality of generalised eigenspaces in general.

The proof is simple: that generalised eigenspace of$~A$ consists by definition of the vectors in the kernel of $\def\id{\,\mathrm{id}}(A-\lambda\id)^k$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$, while the mentioned generalised eigenspace of$~P[A]$ consists of the vectors in the kernel of $(P[A]-P[\lambda]\id)^k$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$. But since $\lambda$ is clearly a root of $P-P[\lambda]$, the latter polynomial is divisible by $X-\lambda$, say $P-P[\lambda]=(X-\lambda)Q$, and then $(P-P[\lambda])^k=(X-\lambda)^kQ^k$ is a multiple of $(X-\lambda)^k$, and any vector annihilated by $(X-\lambda)^k[A]=(A-\lambda\id)^k$ is also annihilated by $(P-P[\lambda])^k[A]=(P[A]-P[\lambda]\id)^k$, which is the desired inclusion.

By hypothesis, the (direct) sum of the generalised eigenspaces for all eigenvalues$~\lambda$ of$~A$ fills the whole space. But each one is contained in the generalised eigenspace for the corresponding eigenvalue$~P[\lambda]$ of$~P[A]$, so the sum of those generalised eigenspaces for all occurring values$~P[\lambda]$ also fills the whole space, and those values constitute the entire spectrum of$~P[A]$. Obviously the generalised eigenspace for$~\mu$ is given by the mentioned direct sum.